# Why does populating this array segfault?

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am having a bit of trouble with the following code that appears to be causing a segmentation fault at the indicated line. I'm trying to create an array of 8 bit unsigned integers in order to instantiate an OpenCV Mat object with, however the segfault occurs partway through the loop that populates the array.

It appears to happen at a different iteration each time, leading me to suspect that something is getting deallocated by GC, but I can't determine what.

**SignDetector.c**

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_xxx_detectBlobs(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jintArray in)
{
    jint *contents = (*env)->GetIntArrayElements(env, in, NULL);

    threshold(contents, PIXEL_SAMPLE_RATE);
    detectBlobs(contents);

    (*env)->ReleaseIntArrayElements(env, in, contents, 0);
}
```

**BlobDetector.cpp**

```
void detectBlobs(jint *contents)
{
    LOGD("Call to detectBlobs in BlobDetector.cpp");

    uint8_t *thresholded = (uint8_t*) malloc(frame_size);

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < frame_size - 1; i++)
        thresholded[i] = (contents[i] == WHITE) ? 0 : 1; // Segfaults partway through this loop.
```

frame_size is simply the number of pixels in an image, which is also equivalent to the length of the jintArray that the image is passed to native code in.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `frame_size` doesn't hold the correct value at the time when `detectBlobs` is called. It may even be uninitialized at the time. The beauty of using global variables is that you never know who's shooting at your foot at any given time.

Comment: This looks like C89, not C++.

Comment: Is the size of the array from `GetIntArrayElements` the same size as `frame_size`? Try calling `(*env)->GetArrayLength(env, in);` and checking the size.

Comment: This does not appear to be the case. I have both verified that the value of frame_size is correct at the time of calling detectBlobs, and have substituted it for a hard coded constant for testing purposes. The fault still occurs.

Comment: I have actually messed up the formatting slightly, the two functions are from different files, will edit for clarity. detectBlobs is in a c++ file, the JNI function is indeed C89.

Comment: Add some test lines prior to the `for` loop. For example, try `thresholded[frame_size - 2] = 0;` and `if (contents[frame_size - 2] == 0) i = 1;` and see which, if either, faults.

Comment: check if the result of `(*env)->GetArrayLength(env, in);` is greater then or equal to `frame_size`. In fact you should add a check to ensure this before calling `detectBlobs`.

Comment: After trying all the suggestions here, and becoming somewhat frustrated, I simply restarted the AVD I was using for testing and the problem stopped occurring. How anticlimatic! Will submit this as an answer as soon as I am able to. Damn anti-spam measures!

Comment: BTW, unless you intend to avoid the last byte of your buffer, your loop indexing is not processing the buffer's final element.

Comment: Yeah, this was something that shouldn't have made it into the sample code above. There was an unrelated issue where frame_size was being initialised one value higher than it should have been, and I was just making sure that it was not that issue striking again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to resolve this by simply restarting my AVD on the Android emulator. Problem appears to not occur on a real device either, so I can only conclude that something exploded in the virtual device's RAM.

Comment: You can accept your own answer in 18 hours? How... frustrating.